# Spring: Nature of @Import in @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-aop

How does importing one `@Configuration` to another actually works in *Spring*? I have figured out, typically only *one* context is created even when there are multiple `@Configuration` files involved. Different configurations just balances the bean definitions to logical units, right? In the end, everything are imported to *Root context*. But the question is, in which order the import is actually done. I can imagine to scenarios.

Individual `@Configuration` creates their own *private context*, which is initialized before/parallel with the root context, and in the end is merged with the *Root context* using `@Import`. Thus, those configurations doesn't have access to *Root context* out of box, and may cause ambiguity when performing autowiring and AOP proxying on business objects across different configurations.

or

When importing `@Configuration`, the parent (*Root context*) is initialized first, and *provides the context* for additional configurations to perform their logic against. Thus, parent can do all the *component scanning* and imported configurations will have those beans available at any time. This means more centralized design and smaller risk for dependency issues.

I'm curious which way Spring does it, because I'm getting strange circular dependency issues when working with *method level security* on Spring, which uses AOP proxies. I pushed isolated sample of the problem in github, if somebody minds to enlighten me.

https://github.com/nostalgiatune/SpringCircularDependency

Comment: Obviously your configuration will fail. You have a bean which is needed to bootstrap the security, however that bean is secured and you are trying to inject a bean into a configuration file which itself is configuring that bean. What should spring do. The import doesn't create additional contexts there wil be only a single one for the root and one for the servlet (in total 2). importing things doesn't change this. Don't auto wire the dependency just reference the method where you need it.

Comment: I don't see how this is obvious. UserDetailsService is used to configure WebSecurity. UserDetailService references a bean (UserService) secured by GlobalMethodSecurity. I'm not even autowiring anything to GlobalMethodSecurity configuration. So is the GlobalMethodSecurity dependent of WebSecurity's configure calls? If so, I don't see any logical connection why. I would just expect GlobalMethodSecurity to proxy that secured bean independently before autowiring it to WebSecurity configuration and building the authentication manager. Or does GlobalMethodSecurity use that authentication manager?

Comment: What you say is actually the issue... The `UserService` needs to be proxied, however cannot do so until Spring Security has finished configuring, for this it needs the `UserService` for your custom `UserDetailsService`. The interceptor for applying the method security needs some of general the security classes like an `AuthenticationManager` (which has nothing to do with web btw). Also if it wouldn't even work you would never be able to authenticate, as you have applied security to a method before security could even be applied.

Comment: I understand now. So basically the problem is constructor injection. If I autowire `UserService` to `UserDetailsService` using field injection, I don't get AOP exception but `AuthenticationManger` required exception and configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) is never run though. Doesn't this mean that method level security is applied **first**? Or does again in this case configure wait the autowiring of bean. So nothing changed and the design of using method security in UserDetailsService itself is fundamentally flawed and impossible to solve. Then how I can apply method security to DAO layer

Comment: It is only delaying the wiring, it doesn't solve the issue. It might even be so that the bean would become wired **without** security because it is used early on and that could make it not eligible for proxying.

Comment: So basically my only choice is to use unsecured DAO directly in UserDetailsService to avoid circular dependency between those two configurations, right? Client will use DAO through service anyway, and it should be easy to make it secured when it doesn't contribute in the security bootstrap process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110634/discussion-between-tuomas-toivonen-and-m-deinum).